# iOS 9 - App Transport Security wont load XML files

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-9-beta3, app-transport-security

I am upgrading my app to iOS9. To Support ATS i had shifted all my urls to https. 
But ATS is throwing below error on XML files. The JSON files located at the same location have no problem.

**App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.**

JSON URL: https://www.example.com/content/123.xml

XML URL: https://www.example.com/content/123.json

Please suggest what might be the issue ?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands in Terminal :

```
curl -v 'https://www.example.com/content/123.xml'
curl -v 'https://www.example.com/content/123.json'
```

It is highly probable that your server doesn't support SSL and redirects your url towards a standard http download.

If this is the case there will be a `Location` header that indicates the new url.

Comment: When i tried curl i got the response - ***<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.example.com/content/123.xml">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>**** but the url i am using is HTTPS protected. do you think this is an issue from my server side ?

Comment: Can you show me the entire output of curl, including http headers ? What is the value of the Location header ? Is it a http or https link ?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your app info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your App's plist add:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```